# How to read complex scala type definition as in ```type Pipe[F[_], -I, +O] = Stream[F, I] => Stream[F, O] ```

Tags: scala, generics, scala-cats

`type Pipe[F[_], -I, +O] = Stream[F, I] => Stream[F, O]`

I understand `F[_]`, `-I` , `+O`. The missing part is `F` in the right. Why not `Stream[F[_]]`?
I guess the F in the left and right have different meaning. Is there any official doc about the rule to write type definition?

I check the kind of Stream,

```scala
scala> :kind fs2.Stream
fs2.Stream's kind is X[+F[A1],+A2]
```

in another case:

```
scala> trait Functor [F[_]] {
     |    def map[A,B] (fn: A=>B)(fa: F[A]): F[B]
     | }
trait Functor

scala> :kind Functor
Functor's kind is X[F[A]]
```

why the `F[A]` is not replaced by F? Of course, I am confused with different concepts, but where should I learn them in one places.

Answer (score 4):

> I guess the F in the left and right have different meaning

More precisely, the underscore `_` on the left and right have different meaning. Former represents anonymous type parameter, whilst latter represents a proper wildcard type. Future versions of Scala 3 should eventually make the meaning the [same](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html)

> It also removes the wart that, used as a type parameter, `F[_]` means
> `F` is a type constructor whereas used as a type, `F[_]` means it is a
> wildcard (i.e. existential) type. In the future, `F[_]` will mean the
> same thing, no matter where it is used

To illustrate the point consider

```
scala> trait Foo[F[_]]
// defined trait Foo

scala> type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[F[_]]
1 |type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[F[_]]
  |                     ^^^^
  |         Type argument F[?] does not have the same kind as its bound [_$1]

scala> type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[F[?]]
1 |type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[F[?]]
  |                     ^^^^
  |         Type argument F[?] does not have the same kind as its bound [_$1]

scala> type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[([x] =>> F[x])[?]]
1 |type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[([x] =>> F[x])[?]]
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |       Type argument F[Any] does not have the same kind as its bound [_$1]
```

Note how underscore on the right is equivalent to

```
([x] =>> F[x])[?]
```

where type lambda `[x] =>> F[x]` is applied on proper type `?`, which results in a proper type `([x] =>> F[x])[?]`. But `Foo` is higher order type constructor which expects another type constructor as an argument, not a proper type. Hence the following works

```
scala> type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[F]
// defined alias type Bar[F] = Foo[F]

scala> type Bar[F[_]] = Foo[[x] =>> F[x]]
// defined alias type Bar[F] = Foo[F]
```

Note how type lambda `[x] =>> F[x]` has to be passed to `Foo` "unapplied".

Comment: type Pipe[F[_], -I, +O] = Stream[F, I] => Stream[F, O]   could be 'read' as type Pipe[[X] =>> F[X], -I, +O] = Stream[F, I] => Stream[F, O]. Is it correct?  This is more approachable